# What is the HTTP_PROFILE browser header and how is it used?

Tags: http, browser, mobile, http-headers

I've just come across the `HTTP_PROFILE` header that seems to be used by mobile browsers to point to an `.xml` document describing the device's capabilities.

Doing a Google search doesn't turn up any definitive resources on what this is and how it should be used, can anyone point me to something along the lines of a spec/W3C standard?

Answer (score 2):

I think you may find http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UAProf to be of interest?

Answer (score 1):

I just found this page: http://www.mobileok.kr/eng/develop2/ddrserver.php

It didn't seem to be authoritative at first glance from the search results, but looks like it might be.

Answer (score 1):

Device Atlas, Wurfl or TeraWurfl are well worth looking into if you want to do some proper mobile device detection. These provide easy access to device properties so you can use content adaptation techniques to serve pages and content which is carefully optimised for the device being used.